# Using ABCPDF to generate document in memory instead of saving on physical drive

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, abcpdf

I was looking into example of ABCPDF using:
[Examples of ABC PDF](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/)

The problem is: It always saves the document on the physical drive. Is there any way to generate PDF document in memory and use content disposition to render the document

Thank you

Comment: Save writes to a stream so why don't you Save to memorystream?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the `Save()` function is able to take a `Stream`.  Make a new `MemoryStream` and save it to that.

http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/doc/1-methods/save.htm

Also, `Attachment` takes a `Stream`.

So:

```
Attachment data = new Attachment(yourMemoryStream, MediaTypesNames.Application.Pdf);
ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Doc.GetData to get the PDF as an array of bytes. If this type of raw data is what you want then this will be more efficient than using a MemoryStream.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your PDF to a stream using the `GetData()` function in ABCPDF.
Then write the bytes out to the browser with the appropriate header information.

```
Dim pdfbytestream as Byte() = oPDF.GetData()
oPDF.Dispose() 'free up unused object

Dim myRandomID As String = Year(Now()).ToString + Month(Now()).ToString + Day(Now()).ToString + Hour(Now()).ToString + Minute(Now()).ToString + Second(Now()).ToString

'Write it out to the browser.  
Response.ClearHeaders()
Response.ClearContent()
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
If pdfbytestream Is Nothing Then Response.AddHeader("content-length", 0) Else Response.AddHeader("content-length", pdfbytestream.Length.ToString())
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" & myRandomID & ".pdf?" & Now.Millisecond)
Response.BinaryWrite(pdfbytestream)
```